# Android First Volley request takes longer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley, android-networking

so I've made an Android application which retrieves data from an API using Volley Framework with a GET request. The problem is that the first request that I make takes around 10 seconds to respond and then if I relaunch the app this same request only takes like 2-3 seconds. If I wait like 2 hours then I restart the app it again takes 10 seconds. I was wondering why this first request takes so long.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with the API and not Android/Volley. Could be caching, could be a process on the server needs time to wake up. Many possibilities

Comment: Ok thanks I'll check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ivan Wooll I found the problem.
As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115999/azure-app-service-websites-has-slow-response-times-after-being-idle-for-some-tim), I'm using Azure App Service and by default the website is taken down after 20 minutes of inactivity and it has to restart after that, that's why the first request takes so long.